# Installing nodejs giving me an error - for Ethereum

Tags: node.js, ethereum

I am trying to install nodejs based on a video that I am watching (installing Ethereum) and I am getting an error. I also tried using (sudo -i) but it is still giving me an error - see below.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc
/usr/local/bin/testrpc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js
```

> fsevents@1.1.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/fsevents
>   node install

sh: node: command not found

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
>   node lib/post_install.js

```
sh: node: command not found
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall: `node lib/post_install.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

npm

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Comment: Sorry - this is new for me... do I write this directly in the terminal?
I tried it and I get: sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: what is your operating system ?

Comment: Mac OS - High Sierra

Comment: Then, please check this one https://www.codementor.io/mercurial/how-to-install-node-js-on-macos-sierra-mphz41ekk